# Set newline character in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I spool output of my query to file using `sqlplus` under Windows so I get CRLF as a new line character in spooled file. I want to set just LF as a new line character cuz my file will be imported in *nix system.
Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know of a sqlplus setting for this, but some other options are:

1. Use a sqlplus client on a Unix/Linux machine to connect to the database and spool using it (the sqlplus client platform determines the file format)
2. Use either an `dos2unix` utility or a more likely available `tr -d '\015' < windowsfile.txt > unixfile.txt` command to convert the file to Unix format once it's copied to the Unix system
3. Where do you import this file - maybe the target system's flat file loader supports ignoring the extra characters?

Answer (score -1):

There is not way to set   the scape caracter in sqlplus.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm

Instead you can use :

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( char(13));`

or

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( char(10));`

if you are using DBMS_OUTPUT and do not use the method put_line.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm
http://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=321

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to use plain `spool`ing to file to improve speed as I have to extract about tens of gigabytes from DB.